# Can I see all part properties in LTspice?

Tags: analog, ltspice, simulation

[image: schematic]

I'm a beginner at using LTspice, and I want to see all the part properties in one slide.

Like this:

R1 : 10k
M1 : W= 10u, L=10u ....
M2 : W= 50u, L=10u ....

How can I do this?

Comment: try opening the save file using a text editor

Comment: Or use the "view netlist" command after running a simulation.

Comment: I accomplished my purpose by entering view -> netlist. Thanks a lot.